# How to print numbers from 0 to 100 that are divisible by 3 and also 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie to programing and i am doing python related exercises and i ran into this problem, where i have to print all the numbers divisible by 3 and also 5.

I know it is somehow related to the for loop with range but i cant figure it out.

I tried looking for solutions but those are out of my league i don't understand them.

```
for number in range (0, 100, 3):
    j = number / 5
    print (j)
```

i tried it like this but i get decimals for answer

Comment: You want to print a certain subset of the numbers between 0 and 100, so your print statement should just be `print(number)`.  The question then becomes *which* of these do you want to print, and which do you want to skip, which cries out for one or more `if` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the modulus '%', which returns the decimal part (remainder) of the quotient.

```
for i in range(100): # Numbers between 0 and 100
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
        # If i is divisible by 3 and i is also divisible by 5 then print it
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

One optimization, number divisible by 3 and 5 must end with `0` or `5`, so we can iterate with `step=5` and check only if number is divisible by 3:

```
print([n for n in range(0, 100, 5) if not n % 3])
```

Prints:

```
[0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90]
```

EDIT: 3 and 5 don't have common divisors, so it's enough to iterate with step 15:

```
print([n for n in range(0, 100, 15)])
```

Prints:

```
[0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for number in range(100):
    if (number % 5 == 0) and (number % 3 == 0):
        print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an if statement in that code and a couple small tweaks. I do not think you need the third argument in the for loop because that changes the increment. The %, or modulus is remainder division. So if remainder division returns 0 then we know that number is divisible by that number. We use an and statement to make sure that the number is divisible by 3 and 5

```
for number in range (0, 100):
    if (number % 15 == 0):
        print (number)
```

Comment: 3 and 5 have no common divisors, so that boils down to `number % 15 == 0`

Comment: Good point. This will probably lead to a small increase in performance. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
print([n for n in range(0, 100, 5) if not n % 3])
```

Comment: `print([n for n in range(0, 100, 15)])` is even easier and does the same.

Comment: @AdrianW You Right <3